# how to store uibutton value in database?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uipickerview

I have one `UIPickerView` and when user click on `UIButton` then `UIPickerView` will appear and user select value from `UIPickerView` and this value display on `UIButton`.
i want to store `UIButton` value in core database for iOS swift application.

Comment: already u have the method for save to local database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store the value in a button. Buttons are view objects, not model objects. Saving state data to a view object violates the MVC design pattern.

In your picker view code, both store the value in a property of your view controller and display it to you button.

Then you can write code to save your property value to core data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead database. I propose to store this value in NSUserDefaults

Write value:

```
NSString *title = [button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:title forKey:@"kButtonTitle"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Read value:

```
NSString *title = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"kButtonTitle"];
```

**Swift**

Read value:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("kButtonTitle") as? [String]
```

Write value:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue, forKey: "kButtonTitle")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: i want to store value in core database.  is there any link or code for storing value in core data from uibutton .